# Unconditional bases equivallent to permutations of basis elements.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

On page 9 of *The Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces: Volume I* I found the following:

> "A basis $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is said to be an *unconditional basis* provided that $\sum \alpha_n x_n$ converges unconditionally whenever it converges. This is equivalent to saying that every permutation of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is also a basis."

How are those two statements equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

Let $X$ be a Banach spacce.

1) $(y_n)$ is a basis of $X$ if and only if each $x\in X$ has a unique representation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i y_i$.

2) If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty z_i$ converges unconditionally to $z$, then any rearangement of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty z_i$ converges to $z$.

3) If $(x_n)$ is a basis of $X$ with coefficient functionals $(x_n^*)$ and if $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_{\pi(i)}$, then $x_{\pi(i)}^* x= \alpha_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @David. I now see why if a basis is unconditional then all of its permutations are also bases. Is the reverse also true? If all permutations of a given basis are bases, is the original basis unconditional?

Comment: @ZLewis Yes. Let $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^*( x) x_i$  and let $\pi$ be a permutation of the integers. Then since $(x_{\pi(i)})$ is a basis, $x$ has an expansion $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_{\pi(i)}$.  By 3), we must have $\alpha_i=x_{\pi(i)}^*( x)$. Thus $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{\pi(i) }^*(x) x_{\pi(i)}$ converges.

Comment: Thanks again, @David! Do you know of a reference for (3)?

Comment: @ZLewis It follows since the coefficient functionals of a basis are continuous. If $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x_{\pi(i)}$, then for each $j$,  $x_{\pi(j)}^* x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n x_{\pi(j)}^* (\alpha_i x_{\pi(i)})= \alpha_j$. Any text that covers Schauder bases  from the ground up will have a proof that the coefficient functionals of a Schauder basis are continuous.