# If every rearrangement of a Schauder basis is also a basis, it is an unconditional one

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

> Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Schauder basis for the Banach space $X$. Suppose for any bijection $\sigma:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $(e_{\sigma(n)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is also a Schauder basis, then is it true that $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an unconditional Schauder basis?(The question is raised by one of my friends. The converse is part of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Unconditionality).)

I have tried very hard to prove that 
for any $x \in X$, there exists $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}a_n e_n=x=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}a_{\sigma(n)} e_{\sigma(n)}$$

Since there is no conditions about the absolute convergence, we cannot use the proof for "absolute convergence $\Rightarrow$ unconditional convergence".
Can anybody show me a proof or an counterexample for this?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855735/), specifically the comments to the answer. I believe your question is addressed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Mitra wrote in [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855796), the continuity of coordinate functionals is the key here. To each Schauder basis $B=(x_n)$ we associate coordinate functionals $\phi_{B,n}$ such that $\phi_{B,n}(x)=c_n$ where $\sum_{ n} c_n x_n = x$. By construction, $\phi_{B, n}(x_m)=0$ for $m\ne n$.

Since the permuted family $B' = (x_{\sigma(n)})$ is still a Schauder basis, we have  $\sum_{ n}\phi_{B',n }(x) x_{\sigma(n)} = x$. The goal is to show that 
$$\phi_{B',n }(x) = \phi_{B,\sigma(n)}(x)$$

The continuity of coordinate functionals (see below) implies
$$
\phi_{B',n}(x) = \lim_{m\to\infty}\phi_{B',n} \left(
\sum_{k\le m} \phi_{B,k}(x) x_{k} \right)
= \lim_{m\to\infty}\phi_{B',n}(x) \left(
 \phi_{B,\sigma(n)}(x) x_{\sigma(n)} \right) = \phi_{B,\sigma(n)} (x)
$$
as claimed. The second equality above holds because $\phi_{B',n} $ vanishes on $x_k$ for $k\ne \sigma(n)$.

For a proof that the coordinate functionals are continuous see, e.g., section 1.1 of [Victor Zeh's notes on Schauder bases](http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~funkana/downloads_general/sem_zeh.pdf). The proof is too long to reproduce here in full, but the main idea is to show that the formula
$$\|x\|_B=\sup_m \left\|\sum_{n\le m} \phi_{B,n}(x) x_n\right\|$$ defines a norm with respect to which $X$ is complete. Since $\|x\|_B\ge \|x\|$ by construction, the open mapping theorem implies  $\|x\|_B\le C\|x\|$ for some $C$. This shows that the partial sums of Schauder basis are continuous with respect to $x$, and the conclusion follows.